# Convert python int into int16_t type

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, types, type-conversion

I know that python int can be converted into an c int type using ctypes.
**But how do I convert a python int into an int16_t type?**

I have tried:

```
import ctypes as ct
my_c_number = ct.c_int16_t(1)
#Apparently ctypes library does not have c_int16_t attribute.
```

Comment: `int16_t` or `uint16_t`? And read the documentation, IIRC, there is a size-correspondance table.

Comment: Either. Yes there is, but it doesn't mention any of the _t types or even the int size types.

Answer (score 1):

How about `ctypes.c_int16`? Also supports `ctypes.c_uint16` if you are looking for that.

Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int16 and
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_uint16